# Chart js slowing page in Firefox in Windows 11

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart JS (V 4.4.0) along with plug in for datalabels to render bar chart in my Angular 7 project. Chart is displayed fine in browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox except in Firefox in Windows 11. The chart works fine in Firefox on Windows 10 machine.

The graph just freezes the page showing message from browser "This page is slowing down Firefox. To speed up your browser, stop this page.". I don't see any error in the console. If I remove the chart related code, the page works fine.

I am not able to understand how to fix the issue since there is no specific error message. Any pointer will be helpful to help debug/solve the issue. Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
arrChartDataLabels: string[] = ['Conn1', 'Conn2', 'Conn3'];
chartDataSuccess: number[] = [2,5,6];
chartDataError: number[] = [2,2,2];
chartDataPending: number[] = [0,0,1];

drawChart(element, showlegend) {
    let id = 'cnvID';
    // Get the drawing context on the canvas
        let myContext = (<HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(id)).getContext('2d');
        let myChart = new Chart(myContext, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: this.arrChartDataLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Success',
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(19,156,130)",
          maxBarThickness: 20,
                    data: this.chartDataSuccess,
          datalabels: { labels: 
            { title: 
              { 
                font: { 
                  family: "'Segoe UI', Arial", size: 14, weight: "500"
                },
                color: function(context) {
                  // console.log("context.dataset.backgroundColor", context.dataset.backgroundColor);
                  return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                },
              } 
            } 
          },
                }, {
                    label: 'Errors',
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(240,0,0)",
          maxBarThickness: 20,
                    data: this.chartDataError,
          datalabels: { labels: 
            { title: 
              { 
                font: { 
                  family: "'Segoe UI', Arial", size: 14, weight: "500"
                },
                color: function(context) {
                  return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                }, 
              }
            } 
          },
                }, {
                    label: 'Pending',
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(176, 215, 248)",
          maxBarThickness: 20,
                    data: this.chartDataPending,
          datalabels: { labels: 
            { title: 
              { 
                font: { 
                  family: "'Segoe UI', Arial", size: 14, weight: "500"
                },
                color: function(context) {
                  return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                },
              } 
            } 
          },
                }],
            },
            options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        aspectRatio: 1,
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: ''
                    },
                    datalabels: {
            align: "top",
            display: function(context) {
              return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0;
           },
                      color: 'black',
                    },
          legend: {
            display: false
          }
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
            border: {display: false},
                        stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              display: false
              },
                        grid: {
                        display: false,
                        drawTicks: false,
                        drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
            border: {display: false},
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
              display: true,
              mirror: true,
              labelOffset: 25,
              color: "rgb(51, 51, 51)",
              font: {
                family: "'Segoe UI', Arial",
                size: 16,
                weight: "500"
              },
                        },
                        grid: {
                        display: false,
                        drawTicks: false,
                        drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
        });
  }
```